# In vb2005 how do you simulate a web browser's file download using Net.HttpListener

Tags: vb.net

In vb2005 how do you simulate a web browser's file download using Net.HttpListener?

This current program functions somewhat like a webserver. how when a client from a web browser
asks for a file do i allow them to down load the file? currently the method will tell the browser that there is a file but it will fail after the client oks the file for download.
below is the code im trying to use

```
Dim fname As New IO.FileInfo(cuser.Request.QueryString(itm))
                                hedlst.Add(Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/octet-stream")
                                hedlst.Add(Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "UTF-8")
                                hedlst.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & fname.Name & """")
                                cuser.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                                Me.Invoke(xnl, uname & " begining download of file : " & fname.FullName)
                                writeoutstream(cuser.Response, fname.OpenRead, hedlst)
                                Me.Invoke(xnl, uname & " downloaded file : " & fname.FullName)

  Private Sub writeoutstream(ByRef uret As Net.HttpListenerResponse, ByRef outtxt As IO.Stream, ByVal headers As System.Net.WebHeaderCollection)
    uret.SendChunked = True
    uret.Headers = headers
    outtxt.Position = 0
    Dim cnl(outtxt.Length) As Byte
    outtxt.Read(cnl, 0, cnl.Length)
    uret.OutputStream.Write(cnl, 0, cnl.Length)
    cnl = Nothing
    outtxt.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close must be called on the outgoing stream to tell the browser that the file is done